# UICollectionView change cell spacing

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, cell

I am working on a horizontal collection view which have cells with dynamic size depends on the label size. I want to set cell in the center of the collection view. I am able to achieve this using

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets { return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, leftinset, 0, leftinset) }
```

Now I want to maintain cell spacing. I had Tried

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.0
}
```

But it is not working in this collection view it also reflect on my other collection view. Can any one help me

This is my current output 
[Image of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60jVt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use this methods..

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat 
{
    return 0.0
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex` ?

Comment: sorry for the mistake i have also tried this but there in no reflection on result